# Measure iPhone rotation around body?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, gyroscope

Okay, there must be a solution to my problem, but I don't know how to Google for it as it is a verbose issue.

I want to use an iPhone's sensors to measure a user pointing at a place in their radius.
See this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZlCU.jpg

Is this even possible?
Is there a solution for this out there already?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only two options that you have available are the compass and the sensor aiding API which gives you the direction you are heading to. Other than that, you could implement an algorithm yourself that "learns" user gestures and rely on that. Those are the only options you have (like the Siri gesture activation feature).